# Scheme obtain an element's depth into recursive lists

Tags: scheme

Hello I have thought and done an exercise which is:

Define a function which accepts as first parameter a list which can contain atoms and recursive lists and as second one an atom. Atoms' values don't repeat themselves. Function returns at what depth is located the atom into the list or zero if it is not there. You should use list?

```
 Ejemplo

(profundidad 
‘(c a b (r t) f (1 ((3 4) 5)
 a)
returns:
1  
(profundidad 
‘(c a b (r t) f (1 ((3 4) 5)
 k)
returns:
0  
(profundidad 
‘(c a b (r t) f (1 ((3 4) 5)
 t)
returns:
2  
(profundidad 
‘(c a b (r t) f (1 ((3 4) 5)
 4)
returns:
4
```

My code:

```
(define (profundidad L c)
    (cond
        ((null? L) 0)
        ((equal? (car L) c) 1)
        ((list? (car L)) (+ (profundidad (car L) c) 1))
    (else(profundidad (cdr L) c))))
```

It resolves well plain lists but how do I return from inner lists recursively?

Thank you for your time!.

Answer (score 0):

Your proble is that in the event the recursion on the `car` is `zero?` you need to do the same as the `else` case. What you should do when the first element is `list?`:

```
(let ((car-result (profundidad (car L) c)))
  (if (zero? car-result)
      (profundidad (cdr L) c)
      (+ 1 car-result)))
```

Comment: Thank you Sylwester you made me realize what was the problem thank you.